# An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Migrating my rails app from 3.2 to 4.0.0 and ruby 2.2.2 to 2.2.4

while doing bundle install am getting (An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue) issue.

using ubuntu 14.04LTS.

**This is what happens when i type in the bundle command**

```
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160727-7643-zx17cc.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling debug_inspector.c
linking shared-object debug_inspector.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [debug_inspector.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
Using sass 3.4.22
Using will_paginate 3.0.7
Using uniform_notifier 1.10.0
Installing byebug 9.0.5 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160727-7643-1w1gc0x.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling context.c
compiling locker.c
compiling threads.c
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling byebug.c
linking shared-object byebug/byebug.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [byebug.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/gems/byebug-9.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/byebug-9.0.5/gem_make.out
Using highline 1.7.8
Using net-ssh 3.2.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160727-7643-6baclf.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
Installing ffi 1.9.14 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160727-7643-e5hbz0.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:637:in `try_ldflags'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1780:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:15:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/gems/ffi-1.9.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/ffi-1.9.14/gem_make.out
Using cliver 0.3.2
Using sexp_processor 4.7.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using country_select 1.2.0
Using daemons 1.0.10
Using database_cleaner 1.5.3
Using debugger-ruby_core_source 1.3.8
Using docile 1.1.5
Using dynamic_form 1.1.4
Using encryptor 1.3.0
Installing eventmachine 1.2.0.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160727-7643-14d9qjy.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ssl-dir
    --without-ssl-dir
    --with-ssl-include
    --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
    --with-ssl-lib
    --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
    --with-openssl-config
    --without-openssl-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:637:in `try_ldflags'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1780:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:65:in `pkg_config_wrapper'
    from extconf.rb:92:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/gem_make.out
Using gem_plugin 0.2.3
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using hashie 3.4.4
Using headless 2.2.3
Using multi_xml 0.5.5
Installing libxml-ruby 2.7.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160727-7643-ftfa2z.rb extconf.rb
checking for socket() in -lsocket... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:735:in `try_func'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:966:in `block in have_library'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:961:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:29:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/gems/libxml-ruby-2.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/libxml-ruby-2.7.0/gem_make.out
Using light-daemon 0.9.7
Using systemu 2.4.2
Using memcache-client 1.8.5
Using metaclass 0.0.4
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using mustache 1.0.3
Installing mysql2 0.3.21 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160727-7643-1dru9tp.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1060:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1059:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:15:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/gems/mysql2-0.3.21 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/mysql2-0.3.21/gem_make.out
Using newrelic_rpm 3.9.9.275
Using nori 1.0.2
Installing oj 2.17.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160727-7643-xze21i.rb extconf.rb
>>>>> Creating Makefile for ruby version 2.2.4 on x86_64-linux <<<<<
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling err.c
compiling strict.c
compiling parse.c
compiling cache8.c
compiling scp.c
compiling fast.c
compiling odd.c
compiling reader.c
compiling compat.c
compiling sparse.c
compiling object.c
compiling hash.c
compiling resolve.c
compiling saj.c
compiling oj.c
compiling hash_test.c
compiling dump.c
compiling circarray.c
compiling val_stack.c
linking shared-object oj/oj.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [oj.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/gems/oj-2.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/oj-2.17.1/gem_make.out
Using parallel 1.9.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using power_assert 0.3.0
Using slop 3.6.0
Using rails-simple-search 0.9.9
Using require_all 1.3.3
Using ruby-progressbar 1.8.1
Using rbx-require-relative 0.0.9
Installing rjb 1.5.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160727-7643-r362l.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:53:in `<main>': JAVA_HOME is not set. (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/gems/rjb-1.5.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vpidev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@ping/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/rjb-1.5.3/gem_make.out
Using rubyzip 1.2.0
Using rubygems-update 1.4.2
Using websocket 1.2.3
Using simplecov-html 0.10.0
Using temple 0.7.7
Using tabs_on_rails 1.3.3
Using minitest-test 1.1.0
Using activesupport 4.0.13
Using gyoku 1.0.0
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using httpi 0.9.5
Using rack-utf8_sanitizer 1.3.2
Using mime-types 3.1
Using sprockets 3.6.3
Using concurrent-ruby-ext 1.0.2
Using fastimage 1.7.0
Using turn 0.9.7
Using better_errors 2.1.1


An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing build dependencies.  Do the following:

> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get install build-essential

Then run bundler again.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp` means that it can't find the gmp library. Try running:

`sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev`

Then `bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
```

You're missing the linux library gmp-devel

Also, https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1727 indicates that the later issues might be down to bundler not being able to locate a version of gcc on your linux box.