# Ruby on rails bundle installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

i'm new in ruby on rails. I'm using windows.
I get error when i type bundle.

An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.

How i can fix it?

Comment: it seems that you trying to install `debug gem` am I Right ?

Comment: Actually i don't know. I know that i'm installing ruby on rails with installation guide from this site [link](https://github.com/CareerFoundry/rails-vm#start-rails-server-inside-vm)

Comment: just remove that `Gem` and run bundle install. later on add `byebug` gem in to your gem file .

Comment: Sorry, how to remove Gem ?

Comment: Ha ha ..Its okey ..Find Gemfile in your project and search for 'debug_inspector' then remove it

Comment: Didn't found debug_inspector, checked few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post would suggest you're missing build dependencies: [An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606544/an-error-occurred-while-installing-debug-inspector-0-0-2-and-bundler-cannot-c)
Try running these commands and see if that works, otherwise run `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` and post the full error message.

Comment: Didn't worked so i run gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2' and get:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.

Comment: That just means your user doesn't have permissions to write to the gem directory. Change permissions of the directory recursively to the current user with chown -R $USER:$USER /var/lib/gems. If you're using the default installed ruby you might want to follow the steps in the answer to this post to get rbenv/rvm and ruby setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720892/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-var-lib-gems-2-3-0-directory

Comment: Thank you, bundle is installed.
But i can't open my localhost.
There are more steps what to do ?

Comment: Did you run "rails server" to start the server? it should tell you the port at which your app is running on localhost, which for rails defaults to port 3000, so your app should be running at  "localhost:3000"

Comment: Ok working, just restarted terminal. Thank you for help!