# Debug inspector error when trying to do bundle install for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, bundle-install

Brand new to coding (started about an hour ago).

Using Mac terminal, trying to do

```
bundle install
```

But I keep getting this error.

```
An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: missing a `'` on the end of your command.

Comment: That seemed to fix the '>' thing but I still get an error message:                                  `error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [debug_inspector.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Ian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Ian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out`

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606544/an-error-occurred-while-installing-debug-inspector-0-0-2-and-bundler-cannot-c